# SQL Referencing a particular table chosen from a row value in another table

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

I've got a database called SimpleCredentials in which there is a table called `dbo.Properties` which has (**PK**) `UserID` and then some other attributes like `Name, Date of Birth` etc. There is another Primary Key attribute called *ExtendedCredentials* which is a string `dbo.UserID`. So, for example the user with `UserID = S-1-5-21-2177` will  have the string `dbo.S15212177` in their *ExtendedCredentials* column.

I've got another database called ExtendedCredentials. For every User there is a unique table in that database. Using the previous example, there will be a table called `dbo.S15212177`.

So, if I have 100 users there will be 100 rows in the `dbo.Properties` table in the SimpleCredentials database, and there will be 100 unique tables incorporating their UserID in the *ExtendedCredentials* database.

I want to create an entity relationship diagram, and eventually a MS SQL schema, but how do I represent the multiplicity of `dbo.UserIDs` and their relationship to their `dbo.UserID` string attribute in `dbo.Properties`?

Am I getting something fundamentally wrong here?

You may ask why I don't have a single database called *ExtendedProperties* with a single table in which each row is the `UserID` PK and the various extended properties are contained in columns. The simple answer is that some properties are themselves tables. Not every user has the same attributes in those tables. And I can't know ahead of time (a priori) what the full set of user extended property attributes is. So each user gets a table of their own.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Better way is to not have 100 tables - have 1 table for all users. Why would users have different attributes - how many differences? Some empty fields per record is more tolerable than 100 tables. Consider an entity/attribute/value table related to Users table. Is that a SSN used in table name?

Comment: A user "Tom" can have the attribute "publications" and "publicationType" and "publicationDates" and another user "Dick" can have attributes "speeches" and "speechTopic" and "speechVenues" and "speechVenueDates" and these are very different. So in dbo.Properties user Tom it will point to database ExtendedProperties and table dbo.Tom where the column headings are "publications" and "publicationType" and so on and each row has his publications. For Dick in dbo.Properties it would point to database ExtendedProperties table dbo.Dick column headings "speeches" and "speechTopic" etc very different

Comment: Hi - sorry but that's not how databases should be designed - as described those not attributes of a User. You should have tables for Users, Publications and Speeches and you relate users with Publications/Speeches via foreign keys (if a Speech/Publication can only have a single user) or with intersection tables (If there is a M:M relationship)

Comment: Yes, I know that's not really how to design a database. The trouble is the extended properties could be anything. Publications, speeches, recipes, sports, cars, holidays... I can't think of every possible category and _a priori_ create a table for it. Basically, there is potentially an infinity of extended properties.